# A cool problem by Godfrey Heathcote

Tags: problems

I didn't get a thought of a better title :)

I am trying to solve a problem which is `white to move and mate in 2 moves`.

To be frank, I am not asking all problems here. On my own I solved more than 50 and stuck up in nearly 15 (*don't worry I will not ask all here itself, I am still trying to solve them*)

```
[FEN "8/qQ5p/3pN2K/3pp1R/4k/7N/1b1PP/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1.Nd4! threatening 2.Rg4#

1...Kxd4 2.Qb4#

1...Bxd4 2.Qb1#

1...Qxd4 2.Qxh7#

2...exd4 2.Qxd5#

Comment: I thought Nd4 was only a waiting move. Somehow, I missed Rg4+.

Answer (score -1):

Qxa7

if d4 then simply move the queen back to b7 (mate)

if black moves the bishop instead then simply Qxh7 (mate)

Comment: "if d4 then simply move the queen back to b7 (mate)" -- not mate: d5 blocks.

Comment: Welcome to Chess Stack Exchange! Unfortunately your answer is not correct. Please consider editing it and explaining further.

Comment: Since your answer is simply wrong, and a correct answer already exists, the polite thing to do would be to delete your answer (unless it could somehow be salvaged).